# How to hold key in phyton which work in games?

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm writing voice control software for disabled people helpful in playing games. I don't know how to manage to hold keyboard keys and mouse buttons in Python, but working in games. So I could, for example, make voice command to move forward in meaning of holding W key. I can spam key presses, it works in some games but in most cases it doesn't. I have been trying different modules but none of seems to work in games. I know how to make button presses but holding keys doesn't work. Probably, I should use native Windows keyboard and mouse functions but I don't know where to start even. I will be glad for any help with the task and advices.

I have tried pynput, pyautogui, keyboard. They all let me press keys but not hold them.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to simulate a keyPress event, then you can simulate a keyHold event. keyPress consists of two events, keyDown and keyUp.

From the [documentation for pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html):
The `press()` function is really just a wrapper for the `keyDown()` and `keyUp()` functions, which simulate pressing a key down and then releasing it up.

I tested all of the following code and it does indeed work as expected:

```
import time
import pyautogui as pg

# I have a text editor opened on, this will move the mouse there and click to focus the prompt
pg.moveTo(300, 300)
pg.click()

# types 'k' repreatedly for 1 seconds, simulating a key holding event
pg.keyDown('k')
time.sleep(1)
pg.keyUp('k')

# only types a single character
pg.press('p')
```

You can also use hold() as a context manager

```
with pg.hold('k'):
    time.sleep(1)
```

this is equal to

```
pg.keyDown('k')
time.sleep(1)
pg.keyUp('k')
```

The documentation from the above link provides all the code samples you need.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I think you didn't understand what I'm trying to do. I don't want recognize key press or hold, I want simulate it. For example, user say go forward and program simulate holding W. I have tried pynput, pyautogui, keyboard modules and no one work in games. They can simulate key presses but not holding.

Comment: @ViperEx76 Sorry my bad, I didn't properly understand your question in the first place. I edited the answer now. I've tested the code, it does the job. :)

Comment: Thanks again but it does not work as you say. It can hold control or shift to simulate ctrl+c for example but it can't hold W key to make character in game walk. The problem is that if you hold physical key on a keyboard it sends key pressed event repeatly, it just hold once.

Comment: Can you post your code? pg.keyDown('k') does hold the key.